# iPad mini capacity determination

Tags: ipad

my iPad mini indicates 19000+ photos, 600 videos and **low disk space**.
I want to buy a new iPad mini that has more capacity.

How can I determine what I have now, so I know how much more capacity the new iPad will need?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings app → General → iPad Storage, and you'll be able to see the total storage capacity of your iPad at the top as XX GB of YY GB Used.

[image]

Here, XX is the space currently used, and YY is the total storage capacity of your iPad mini.

As of now, across different models, iPad mini comes with either 16, 32, 64 or 128 GB of storage capacity.